# String replace by comparing associative array index in php

Tags: php, associative-array, string-matching

My array is

```
Array
(
    [#A] => 12 >  5
    [#B] => 4  >  3
)
```

I want to replace in the expression

```
((#A) OR (#B) AND (#A))
```

by matching the key of the array. So I am expecting result as

```
((12 >  5) OR (4  >  3) AND (12 >  5))
```

Currently I couldn't achieve it. Thanks in advance.

Consider my code segement `

```
$this->logger->debug($datauser);   // [ZN1961] => Array([#A] => 12 >  5 [#B] => 4  >  3 ), [ZN1962] => Array ([#A] => 20 >  5 [#B] => 20  >  3 )
logicexpression = ((#A) OR (#B) AND (#A));

$newArr = array();
foreach ($datauser as $key => $value) {

    foreach ($value as $logname => $cond) {
         if(array_key_exists($logname,$value)){
    $newArr[$key] =str_replace($logname, $cond, $logicexpression);;
}


    }


}
$this->logger->debug($newArr); // here I am always getting ((12 >  5) OR (4  >  3) AND (12 >  5))`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String replace natively supports arrays

```
$array  = [ '#A' => '12 > 5', '#B' => '4 > 3' ];
$string = '((#A) OR (#B) AND (#A))';

$string = str_replace(array_keys($array), $array, $string);
```

So with array keys we can cut out the middle men so to speak.

Test it online

https://3v4l.org/dEMQ6

And of course array keys just gives you an array with the keys as the values.  So in this case

```
$array  = [ 0 => '#A', 1 => '#B'];
```

Then it just matches the position in the "search" array to those in the "replace" array with string replace and wha la.

cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Just loop to the array, then use `str_replace()`

```
$array  = [ '#A' => '12 > 5', '#B' => '4 > 3' ];
$string = '((#A) OR (#B) AND (#A))';

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $string = str_replace($key, $value, $string);
}

echo $string;
```

Comment: PS, sorry to steal your thunder so to speak, I give you a bump Up though.... as compensation.  I also approved your edit.. :-)